# Unable to "Recommend Close" a VLQ question I've flagged

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I flagged to close a question and then found the same question in the Low Quality review queue. I expected to be able to open up the close modal and it recognize that I've flagged it already and count that as a review, but instead it didn't and I have no other valid choice than to skip it.

[image: the close modal]

Is there any way we can make it so that occurrences like this will recognize that I've already voted to close it and count that as a review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, you clicked the close link and the question was closed by @Matt at near the same time. So Matt's action, being a moderator, cancels yours.

Or @Matt closed the question before you got to it after you clicked the "review" link.

Probably more of a coincidental timing thing.

Comment: Makes sense. I'd like to have some confirmation before accepting though :)

Comment: Well the question is closed by Matt and no other names are listed. So, clearly Matt performed the close before anyone else flagged it. If you *actually* flagged it for closure, your username would appear with Matt's. And there is no "close" link if a question has already been closed. So..... has to be a timing thing.