# close vote / recommend deletion bug

Tags: bug, review

So I flagged this question (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/64493) for closure as off-topic, and as I was reviewing Low Quality posts it popped up again for me. So my only choice is to skip.

I saw [this meta question about almost the same thing](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/unable-to-recommend-close-a-vlq-question-ive-flagged) except that in my case the question is still open as of now, so it can't be a matter of timing. Looks like a bug.

So, is there any way the system can see the flag and at least not show the question again or count that as a review?

Comment: 4 year old dupe on MSE: [Low Quality Posts you Have Already Flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193128/307988)

Comment: ooh thanks @Cai I missed that one.